# Minifloat Format

Tags: binary, format

I am currently looking into how to convert a binary minifloat to denary. I have looked all over the internet but no guides so far seem helpful. So far all I know is that it has 1 sign-bit, a 5-bit excess-15 exponent, 10 mantissa bits (with 1 implied bit(*I'm unsure what an implied bit is*)) and it uses standard IEEE rules.

So I come here and ask this question. How does the conversion work and how do you calculate it?

Answer (score 2):

## Short Answer

[image: fprep]

## Longer Answer

Before reading ahead, you may gain some insight by just reading about the 32-bit [floating point format specified by IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).

As you stated in your question, floating point numbers are comprised of three parts - the sign bit, the exponent and the mantissa.  Let's look at the specifics of each as they are apply to the 16-bit minifloat you've described.  For the following, I assume that you have some knowledge of how (unsigned) [binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation) are stored.

```
[] [][][][][] [][][][][][][][][][]
sb  exponent        mantissa
```

## Sign bit

This is more or less self-explanatory - it indicates whether a positive or negative number is being represented.  IEEE specifies that a sign bit of `1` is negative, and a sign bit of `0` is positive.

## Exponent

The exponent gives us our order of magnitude.  You've specified 5-bit excess-15.  Excess-15 represents the offset of the exponent.  *Why is there an offset?* Generally, we want exponents to be able to represent positive *or* negative numbers.  One way to do this is by subtracting (or offsetting) some constant.  In this case, we subtract 15.

Example: `00110` would represent the decimal number `6` if it were an unsigned representation.  However, in our offset-15 representation, `00110` represents `6-15` which is equal to `-9` (decimal).

## Mantissa

The mantissa works in a very similar way to a regular unsigned number, except that the "implied" bit needs some explanation.  Since the order of magnitude part is already taken care of by the exponent, we don't need to represent different orders of magnitudes in the mantissa as well.  Therefore, we assume that the mantissa is a binary number of the form `1.xxxxxxxxxx`, `x`s being `1`s and `0`s.

Example: `0000000001` represents `1.0000000001` (binary) which is equal to `1 1/2^11` or `0.00048828125` (decimal).

## Putting it all together

Once you understand how to decode the mantissa and exponent, this becomes quite a bit like using [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), but in binary instead of decimal: just multiply the mantissa value by 2 raised to the exponent value, and let the sign bit determine sign.

Example: `1010001100000000`

- Mantissa bits: `1100000000`; Mantissa value: `1.11` (bin) or `1.75` (dec)
- Exponent bits: `01000`; Exponent value: `16 - 15` or `1` (dec)
- Sign bit: `1` or "negative"

Putting it all together, we have:

```
(-1)^sb * mantissa * 2^exponent == -1 * 1.75 * 2^1 = -3.5
```

Comment: This covers the major cases for floating point numbers, but there are others numbers (and things that aren't numbers) that floating point numbers can represent in the IEEE specification, namely: [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), and [infinities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Infinities).